# Union-find in a graph structure

Tags: haskell, union-find

I have a record describing a graph as sets of nodes and edges:

```
data MyGraph a = MyGraph {
  nodes :: Set a,
  edges :: Set (a,a),
  components :: UnionFindM a -- ?
}
emptyGraph = MyGraph{
  nodes = empty, edges = empty,
  components = emptyUnionFind singleton union --?
}
addEdge g (a,b) = g{
  edges = (a,b) `insert` (edges g),
  components = (components g) >>= (equate a b) -- ?
}
```

Since I won't ever remove edges, I want to track the connected components using a union-find structure (which I could easily update when adding an edge), because I want to map over the connected components, so it would be useful to keep them as a set of sets, too. And of course I want to get the component for a node.

I found the [equivalence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/equivalence/0.2.3/doc/html/Data-Equivalence-Monad.html) library, which I chose because I can't see how I would create sets with [union-find](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/union-find/0.2/doc/html/Data-UnionFind-ST.html) and [persistent-equivalence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-equivalence-0.3) needs to know the value range.

Now I can create relations, and return the set of sets using:

```
import Control.Monad(liftM)
import Data.Equivalence.Monad
import Data.Set(singleton, union, fromList)
f = runEquivM singleton union $ do
  equate "foo" "bar"
  equate "bar" "baz"
  (liftM fromList) $ mapM classDesc ["foo","bar","baz","one","two"]

>>> f
fromList [fromList ["bar","baz","foo"],fromList ["one"],fromList ["two"]]
```

But: using `fromList` is very naive, it should be possible to get all equivalence classes from the internal data structure directly.

And, more importantly: how can I store the equivalence relation in my data structure?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `Data.Equivalence.Persistent`

```
data MyGraph a = MyGraph {
  nodes :: Set a,
  edges :: Set (a,a),
  components :: Equivalence a
}
emptyGraph :: Ix a => (a, a) -> MyGraph a
emptyGraph range = MyGraph{
  nodes = empty, edges = empty,
  components = emptyEquivalence range
}
addEdge :: Ix a => MyGraph a -> (a, a) -> MyGraph a
addEdge g (a,b) = g{
  edges = (a,b) `insert` (edges g),
  components = equate a b (components g)
}
```

I find the use of `Ix` a little annoying here, but if it works for your purposes then go with it.  Making union-find persistent is an awesome idea explored by [Conchon](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.79.8494) which also includes an implementation proven correct in Coq.  Basically, if you use reverse difference arrays, you get persistent arrays that have the performance of linear arrays a la [Clean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_%28programming_language%29) but can use them in a persistent way at the cost of logarithmic slow down.  Thus, they are suitable for implementing things union-find that involve lots of imperative side effects in a pure functional way.

Comment: Thanks for the papers! Forgot to mention in my question: I don't know the size of the graph in advance, which is why [persistent-equivalence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-equivalence-0.3) isn't suitable either since it has to know the range on construction…